# How could I restrict access to a website hosted using azure webapp to a specific country?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How could I restrict access to a website hosted using azure webapp  to a specific country?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use web.config or use [IP restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) feature of the webapp.

[image]

[web.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/dynamicIpSecurity/) way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <!-- Full Dynamic IP Restriction Documentation: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions -->
      <dynamicIpSecurity> <!-- Change status code by adding the attribute: denyAction="[AbortRequest | Forbidden | NotFound | Unauthorized]" -->
        <!-- Scenario #1: Deny by Concurrent Requests -->
        <denyByConcurrentRequests enabled="true" maxConcurrentRequests="10"/>
        <!-- Scenario #2: Deny by Request Rate -->
        <denyByRequestRate enabled="true" maxRequests="10" requestIntervalInMilliseconds="2000"/>
        <!-- Scenario #3: Combine Deny by Request Rate & Deny by Concurrent Requests -->
      </dynamicIpSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Wrong.  You can't restrict a whole country.

Comment: tell me what prevents you from doing that? are you lazy or?

Comment: How do you restrict UK?

Comment: you trolling? http://lite.ip2location.com/ip-address-ranges-by-country

Comment: Absolutely not, sorry if it sounded like that.  I don't think it's possible to enter all these IPs manually.  There must be some hard limit on the numbers of IPs you can enter.  I'd suggest using a geolocation service.

Comment: well, from the web app perspective this is how you would do that. geolocation service requires code changes? i think you would use `allowUnlisted` and provide specific country ip addresses. nobody said this has to be done manually. you create a list of ips with some service and run a script to generate webapp. i dont think there is any other way using webapp capabilities

Answer (score 1):

It seems Azure Web App cannot restrict the access just by country directly. You can have a try with [Azure CDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-restrict-access-by-country), it can restrict the access by country.